# Is there a chronological reading order for Star Trek books?

Tags: star-trek, suggested-order, star-trek-eu

I just started reading the Star Trek books and would like to know what is the best order for reading so that I can progress chronologically.

Comment: http://www.thetrekcollective.com/p/trek-lit-reading-order.html

Comment: Basically the whole thing is a gigantic mess.

Comment: There was very little collaboration or consultation between the various authors and between the authors and the creative staff behind the shows and films.  Even if you manage to order them (like in the flow chart that Richard linked to), you'll find yourself having to come to grips with numerous contradictions...

Comment: “so that I can progress chronologically” — you mean chronologically in-universe?

Comment: By chronologically i mean chronologically within particular universes.

Comment: For example: after Cadet Kirk i want to read about how he came about his first command.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer:  Yes, some fans think there is a proper order to read star trek novels.

There are several websites:

http://www.maplenet.net/~trowbridge/timeline.htm[1](http://www.maplenet.net/~trowbridge/timeline.htm)

http://www.thetrekcollective.com/p/trek-lit-reading-order.html[2](http://www.thetrekcollective.com/p/trek-lit-reading-order.html)

https://startreklitverse.yolasite.com/[3](https://startreklitverse.yolasite.com/)

http://www.shastrix.com/books/star-trek-reading-order.php[4](http://www.shastrix.com/books/star-trek-reading-order.php)

http://homeofreading.com/star-trek-novel-reading-order/[5](http://homeofreading.com/star-trek-novel-reading-order/)

http://killie-booktalk.blogspot.com/p/star-trek-reading-challenge.html[6](http://killie-booktalk.blogspot.com/p/star-trek-reading-challenge.html)

I don't know if they all agree or if each suggests a different order.

And there is the James Dixon Star Trek chronology, an attempt to put all *Star Trek* movies, episodes, movles, comic books, etc. etc. in chronological order.

Here is a link to one version of it:

http://stng.36el.com/st-tng/trivia/timeline/trek7-notes.html[7](http://stng.36el.com/st-tng/trivia/timeline/trek7-notes.html)

The long answer could be a complicated discusssion of the many problems with putting all the several hundred novels in proper chronological order.  Some of the websites discuss some of the problems in their introductions.